# It is possible to convert styled-component to css

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I have a question.

I wanted to use a css stylesheet, separate from my js file.

I started with stylized component and now I don't know how to convert to css... is it possible?

**example:**

```
color: theme.palette.text.secondary
```

```
padding: theme.spacing(2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use CSS you don't have to use Styled-Component look at this sample project https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/react-jsx it's a good sample for using CSS in JSX react

your style.css file

```
.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

your todo component as you see, you can use "done" class name in it

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {

    // some codes here
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos:</h2>
        <ol>
        {this.state.items.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" disabled readOnly checked={item.done} /> 
              <span className={item.done ? "done" : ""}>{item.text}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        ))}
        </ol>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```